# dual booting ubuntu and window7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows7, no problem with Ubuntu but when I take Windows7 option, I have problems in booting, 50% of the times the screen freezes and lines appear on the screen then I need to restart from the beggining at least 2-3 times . How can solve this probelm, I have a new PC with Intel i7 ? Many thanks for your help Perin

Answer (score 0):

If Windows 7 was pre-installed, the issue should not be related to UEFI.  So as first steps, I would look at GRUB and the Windows bootloader.  See this link for a simple GRUB repair utility: http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

There are a number of ways that GRUB can fail to work properly (not just Ubuntu boot problems), and this will fix most problems related to GRUB.  The most likely cause of GRUB problems is if you had previously installed a dual boot and then upgraded or replaced the Linux installation.  There are sometimes backwards compatibility issues with new versions of GRUB.

See this link for fixing the Windows bootloader: https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/

If everything was working properly before the Ubuntu installation, one of these two things is likely to fix it.  If not, update your question.